# C++: Why accessing class data members is so slow compared to accessing global variables?

Tags: c++, oop, gcc, optimization, clang

I'm implementing a computationally expensive program and in the last days I spent a lot of time getting familiar with object oriented design, design patterns and SOLID principles. I need to implement several **metrics** in my program so I designed a simple interface to get it done:

```
class Metric {
    typedef ... Vector;
    virtual ~Metric() {}
    virtual double distance(const Vector& a, const Vector& b) const = 0;
};
```

the first metric I implemented was the Minkowski metric,

```
class MinkowskiMetric : public Metric {
public:
     MinkowskiMetric(double p) : p(p) {}
     double distance(const Vector& a, const Vector& b) const {
         const double POW = this->p; /** hot spot */
         return std::pow((std::pow(std::abs(a - b), POW)).sum(), 1.0 / POW);
private:
     const double p;
};
```

Using this implementation the code ran **really slow** someone tried a global variable instead of accessing the data member, my last implementation doesn't get the job done but looks like this.

```
namespace parameters {
     const double p = 2.0; /** for instance */
}
```

And the *hot spot* line looks like:

```
        ...
        const double POW = parameters::p; /** hot spot */
        return ...
```

Just making that change, the code runs at least 275 times faster in my machine, using either gcc-4.8 or clang-3.4 with optimization flags in Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Is this a problem a common pitfall?
Is there any way around it?
Am I just missing something?

Comment: Make the double in your `MinkowskiMetric` a `const`.

Comment: Also, did you copy your class `Metric` correctly? `distance` does have a `virtual` in front of it, right?

Comment: Also, if you are going for speed, you might try and familiarize yourself with the concept of static polymorphism. I'm assuming the metrics are called a lot, so you might want to make the metric a template argument.

Comment: I don't think the virtual is the issue, because = 0 implies that the method should be overridden, making the member p const doesn't help it either.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "my last implementation doesn't get the job done"?

Comment: What probably happen is that with your global version, the code is simplified at compile time, thus giving huge improvement.

Comment: You don't show the code which is calling `distance`. I'm assuming it is doing so through a pointer to the object.

Comment: Yes it uses a pointer to a `Metric` object I also tried using a pointer to a `MinkowskiMetric` object with the same results. the optimization flags are the same in both cases, although I understand that the issue is related to the compiler.

Comment: @sjdowling If that's the case, the lack of `virtual` on the `distance` method would explain why things aren't working properly.

Comment: I just reviewed the code, the virtual specifier is present in the `Metric` class but not in the child class.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing `const double POW = this->p` instead of using `this->p` directly? I'm not sure whether the compiler would optimize this anyway, but if it doesn't, that's an extra copy operation that isn't necessary.

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is a cache miss issue. The use of pointer indirection and virtual functions makes me suspect that the cache keeps missing every time it has to look up the `p` member through the object's pointer. Compare that to loading in the global variable where there is one less level of indirection.

Comment: @sjdowling That sounds reasonable but can you think of a way around it?

Comment: @dmg note that `const` is not a compiler optimisation, it's there to prevent bugs in the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the two version is that in one case, the compiler has to load `p` and perform some computation with it, while in the other, you're using a global constant, which the compiler can probably just substitute directly. So in one case, the resulting code probably does this:

1. Load `p`.
2. Call `abs(a - b)`, name the result `c`
3. Call `pow(c, p)`, name the result `d`
4. Call `d.sum()` (whatever that means), name the result `e`
5. Calculate `1.0 / p`, name the result `i`
6. Call `pow(e, i)`.

That's a bunch of library calls, and library calls are slow. Also, `pow` is slow.

When you use the global constant, the compiler can do some calculations by itself.

1. Call `abs(a - b)`, name the result `c`.
2. `pow(c, 2.0)` is more efficiently calculated as `c * c`, name the result `d`
3. Call `d.sum()`, name the result `e`
4. `1.0 / 2.0` is `0.5`, and `pow(e, 0.5)` can be translated to the more efficient `sqrt(e)`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at what is going on here:

```
...
Metric *metric = new MinkowskiMetric(2.0);
metric->distance(a, b);
```

Since `distance` is a virtual function the runtime has to look up the address of the `metric` pointer to load in the virtual function table pointer and then use that to look up the address of the `distance` function for your object.

This is probably incidental to what is happening next:

```
 double distance(const Vector& a, const Vector& b) const {
     const double POW = this->p; /** hot spot */
```

The function has to then look up the address of the `this` pointer (which happens to be explicitly stated here) in order to know from which location to load in the value of `p`. Compare that to the version which uses a global variable:

```
double distance(const Vector& a, const Vector& b) const {
    const double POW = parameters::p; /** hot spot */
...
namespace parameters {
     const double p = 2.0; /** for instance */
}
```

This version of `p` is always going to live at the same address and therefore loading in its value is only ever going to be a single operation and removes a level of indirection which is almost certainly causing a cache miss and causing the CPU to block waiting for data to be loaded from RAM.

So how can you avoid this? Try to allocate objects on the stack as much as possible. This enables a locality of reference known as spatial locality which means that your data is much more likely to be living in the CPU's cache when it needs to load it in. You can see Herb Sutter discussing this issue in the middle of [this talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use OOP in code that should be somewhat performant you'll still have to minimise the amount of memory accesses. This means a change in design. Taking your example (assuming you're evaluating the metric a few times):

```
double MinkowskiMetric::distance(const Vector& a, const Vector& b) const {
     const double POW = this->p; /** hot spot */
     return std::pow((std::pow(std::abs(a - b), POW)).sum(), 1.0 / POW);
}
```

can be turned into

```
template<class VectorIter, class OutIter>
void MinkowskiMetric::distance(VectorIter aBegin, VectorIter aEnd, VectorIter bBegin, OutIter rBegin) const {
    const double pow = this->p, powInv = 1.0 / pow;
    while(aBegin != aEnd) {
        Vector a = *aBegin++;
        Vector b = *bBegin++;
        *rBegin++ = std::pow((std::pow(std::abs(a - b), pow)).sum(), powInv);
    }
}
```

Now you'll access the location of the virtual function and the members of `this` exactly once for a set of `Vector` pairs - adjust your algorithm accordingly to make use of this optimisation.